# sample power-shell script to read values from REST API

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, powershell

I need a sample powershell script to read values/single value from a given RESTFul API. Here is the URL of sample restful URL

http://dummy.restapiexample.com/

Below is the one I tried.But instead of count I wanted to get some employees data.

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees'
$employees = $response.items.Count;
Write-Host "employees=$employees";
Output:
employees= 272
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees'
foreach($item in $response){
    Write-Host "$item"
}
```

this will display each record..

```
Invoke-RestMethod 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees'
foreach($item in $response){
    Write-Host $item.employee_name
}
```

this will display only names.

Comment: Simply use `$response | Format-Table -AutoSize` or `$response | Out-GridView`